# How to match text leading up to an optional trailing element

Tags: regex, ruby

I am trying (with ruby) to pick apart strings with original film titles – which can include bracketed elements themselves – and may include a trailing bracketed element with an alternative title. I need to capture the leading part and the optional trailing alternative title, if present.

Example strings:

1. "Solaris"
2. "Alice Guy-Blaché (1873 – 1968) – Hommage an die erste Filmemacherin der Welt"
3. "Ieri, oggi, domani (Gestern, heute und morgen)"
4. "Your life (in code) – A tribute (L'ultimo hacker)"
5. "Birdman or (The Unexpected Virtue of Ignorance) (Birdman oder (Die unverhoffte Macht der Ahnungslosigkeit))"

For example string 1 I'd want

```
#<MatchData "Solaris" 1:nil>
```

For example string 2 I'd want

```
#<MatchData "Alice Guy-Blaché (1873 – 1968) – Hommage an die erste Filmemacherin der Welt" 1:nil>
```

For example string 3 I'd want

```
#<MatchData "Ieri, oggi, domani" 1:"(Gestern, heute und morgen)">
```

For example string 4 I'd want

```
#<MatchData "Your life (in code) – A tribute" 1:"(L'ultimo hacker)">
```

For example string 5 I'd want

```
#<MatchData "Birdman or (The Unexpected Virtue of Ignorance)" 1:"(Birdman oder (Die unverhoffte Macht der Ahnungslosigkeit))">
```

`.+(?= (\(.+\)))` works for 3 and 4. It doesn't work for 1 and it breaks apart 2.

How to make that optional trailing bracketed element optional in the regular expression?

Example 5 has been added to the original question.

Comment: Does [this](https://regex101.com/r/v7WSPd/1): `"[^"]+?(\([^)]+\))?"` work for you?

Comment: Do you need to handle nested brackets?

Comment: @tadman, no, not required.

Comment: @tadman, and now that I've bumped into Example 5, yes, need to handle nested brackets.

Comment: I figured that day would arrive eventually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
r = /.*[^ ](?= +(\(.*\))\z)|.+/
```

```
"Solaris".match r
  #=> #<MatchData "Solaris" 1:nil> 
"Alice Guy-Blaché (1873 – 1968) – Hommage...der Welt".match r
  # => #<MatchData "Alice Guy-Blaché (1873 – 1968) – Hommage...der Welt" 1:nil> 
"Ieri, oggi, domani (Gestern, heute und morgen)".match r
  #=> #<MatchData "Ieri, oggi, domani" 1:"(Gestern, heute und morgen)"> 
"Your life (in code) – A tribute     (L'ultimo hacker)".match r
  #=> #<MatchData "Your life (in code) – A tribute" 1:"(L'ultimo hacker)">
```

The regular expression can be written in *free-spacing mode* to make it self-documenting.

```
r = /
    .*         # match >= 0 chars
    [^ ]       # match a character other than a space 
    (?=        # begin positive lookahead
      [ ]      # match one space
      (        # start capture group 1 
        \(.*\) # match a left paren, >= 0 chars, right paren
      )        # end capture group 1
      \z       # match end-of-string
    )          # end positive lookahead
    |          # or
    .+         # match > 0 chars (entire string)
    /x         # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

Comment: I found a complication; I've added it to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that does not employ a regular expression. I expect it would be faster than the use of a single regular expression, but also easier to maintain if requirements change in future.

```
def pick_apart(str)
  raise ArgumentError if str.count('(') != str.count(')')
  return [str, ''] unless str.size > 0 && str.end_with?(')')
  n = 1
  idx = (str.size-2).downto(0).find do |i|
    case str[i]
    when ')'
      n += 1
      false
    when '('
      n -= 1
      n.zero?
    else
      false
    end
  end
  [str[0,idx], str[idx..-1]]
end
```

`idx` is the index of the character '(' that corresponds to ')'
 at the end of the string.

```
pick_apart "Solaris"
  #=> ["Solaris", ""] 
pick_apart "Alice Guy-Blaché (1873 – 1968) – Hommage...der Welt"
  #=> ["Alice Guy-Blaché (1873 – 1968) – Hommage...der Welt", ""] 
pick_apart "Ieri, oggi, domani (Gestern, heute und morgen)"
  #=> ["Ieri, oggi, domani ", "(Gestern, heute und morgen)"] 
pick_apart "Your life (in code) – A tribute     (L'ultimo hacker)"
  #=> ["Your life (in code) – A tribute     ", "(L'ultimo hacker)"] 
pick_apart "Birdman (The...Ignorance) (Birdman (Die unverhoffte))"
  #=> ["Birdman (The...Ignorance) ", "(Birdman (Die unverhoffte))"] 
pick_apart "Birdman (The (other) one) (Birdman (Die (other) one))"
  #=> ["Birdman (The (other) one) ", "(Birdman (Die (other) one))"] 
pick_apart ""
  #=> ["", ""] 
pick_apart "(((hey)))"
  #=> ["", "(((hey)))"] 
pick_apart "(((hey))"
  #=> ArgumentError (ArgumentError)
pick_apart "((hey)))"
  #=> ArgumentError (ArgumentError)
pick_apart ")"
  #=> ArgumentError (ArgumentError)
```

Comment: I like the approach of going for balanced brackets. Realizing now, though, that there is no algorithmic way to decide whether `foo (bar)` is an original title `foo` with an alternative title `bar` or an original title `foo (bar)` – outside of language detection.